# Trying to find an easy way for PHP and Mysql DB to do math (AVG MIN MAX) for PHP5.5

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I currently have PHP 5.3 and need to upgrade to at least PHP 5.5/5.6. I have a page that post averages for rental properties. For a while i got away with using mysql but when I upgrade, in need to use mysqli. Below is a code I tried writing in PDO.

```
$hostname = "your_hostname";  
$username = "your_username";  
$password = "your_password";
$db = "database";

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);  

foreach ($dbh->query("SELECT MAX(rent) FROM table WHERE PType ='$PType' AND PState = '$state'") as $row) { 
    $SMR = "" . $row['MAX(rent)'] . "";
}
```

That works in PHP 5.3, but not PHP 5.5/5.6. I have tried changing the `$dbh` line to this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysqli:host=$server;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
```

The error log came up with a driver error.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you post the driver error from the log? Also, I don't see where you set the `$server` variable. Looks like you have a mismatch between `$hostname` and `$server`. And your other variables, too. Is that the actual code you're using?

Comment: You don't need to change `mysql` to `mysqli` in the `PDO` initialization. `PDO` already uses modern client libraries under the hood, and this `mysql` has nothing to do with the `mysql_*()` functions you shouldn't use anymore. You can absolutely keep using `new PDO('mysql:...')`. What errors are you getting when you try the same code you used to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion here as far as what's required to upgrade. The [`mysql_query()`](https://secure.php.net/mysql_query) function, and related `mysql_*()` functions, were deprecated starting with PHP 5.5, and were removed in PHP7.

However, this has nothing to do with the word `mysql` in `PDO`'s initialization. The syntax shown [here in PDO's documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) is correct. Usage of the legacy `mysql_*()` functions should be replaced with MySQLi, but PDO is not affected.

Now, I'm not sure whether or not you actually tried the old PDO code and it failed, or if you're just thinking you need to make changes for best-practices. But if `$row['MAX(rent)']` isn't working for you, and even if it is, for clarity, you might want to just assign it an alias:

```
foreach ($dbh->query("SELECT MAX(rent) as MaxRent FROM table WHERE PType ='$PType' AND PState = '$state'") as $row) { 
    $SMR = "" . $row['MaxRent'] . "";
}
```

Comment: Using that alias works. I've had to add the try..catch. The driver issue is gone! You guys rock!!!